Keep the OHIF screen intact after pressing the link to open weasis
i'm using OHIF to view dicom file. I have created a mode like the picture :
I configured that mode as follows :
routes: [
    {
    layoutTemplate: () => {
      const hostname = window.location.hostname;
      const url = `$dicom:rs --url="http://${hostname}:8080/dcm4chee-arc/aets/DCM4CHEE/rs" --                     request="studyUID=2.25.270>      const newUrl = "weasis://" + encodeURIComponent(url);
      window.open(newUrl, '_blank'); // '_blank' để mở trong tab mới
  //      return null;
    },
  },
],

To redirect to weasis image viewer and successes. Weasis opened in new tab on Browser. But this mode still redirect to "https://localhost:300/instancestudyUID=...".
Please help me how to open weasis but the current OHIF page won't redirect
